# Quando é que o "trem" desapareceu de Portugal, e o "comboio" do Brasil?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas

Os brasileiros chamam ***trem*** ao que os portugueses chamam ***comboio***. Mas já houve um tempo em que os dois nomes eram usados nos dois países (grafia original, ênfase minha):

> Quem viaja a cavallo ou em carro de bois sente um alegrão doido quando vê na estrada, ao longe, outro cavalleiro ou quando ouve o rincho de outro carro de bois; e no ***trem***? Se a gente vê vir, na mesma linha, outro ***comboio*** em sentido contrario, só tem uma coisa a fazer: é encomendar a alma ao Creador, porque está frito. (Escritor brasileiro [Coelho Netto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelho_Neto), ‘Um Simples’ in *A Bico de Penna*, 1904.)
>
> De repente o ***comboio*** recomeçou a rolar, muito sereno. Em breve apareceram as luzinhas mortas duma estação abarracada. Um conductor, com o casacão de oleado todo a escorrer, trepou ao salão:―e por elle soubemos, emquanto carimbava apressadamente os bilhetes, que o ***trem***, muito atrazado, talvez não alcançasse em Medina o ***comboio*** de Salamanca! (Escritor português [Eça de Queiroz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%A7a_de_Queir%C3%B3s#Obras), [*A Cidade e as Serras*](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bv000081.pdf), 1901.)

Entretanto em Portugal o *trem* extinguiu-se, e no Brasil o *comboio* tornou-se uma espécie rara que apenas sobrevive nalguns documentos técnicos. Como e quando é que isto aconteceu?

Comment: Quando?  Sem pesquisar não posso responder; quando nasci já se falava "trem" e pouco se ouvia "comboio", mesmo quando tendo outros significados.  Temos também uma diferença quanto ao nome daquele veículo que os portugueses chamam de "elétrico" e os brasileiros chamam de "bonde".

Comment: Estava a par do "bonde". Resta saber também se já havia naquele tempo uma preferência por comboio em Portugal e por bonde no Brasil, e se eram os escritores que gostavam de variar.

Comment: Talvez *trem* tivesse um significado ligeiramente diferente de *comboio*. Dá-me ideia que esses dois autores usam *trem* quando viajam no dito e *comboio* quando é outro. Mas poderá ser mera coincidência.

Comment: É verdade, mas é coincidência. Estive ontem a folhear a Cidade e as Serras, e o Jacintho também diz *comboio* para se referir ao próprio em que está.

Comment: Nos realmente precisamos de um [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams) pt-BR e pt-PT para responder a isso

Comment: Pois, isto com um Ngram fazia-se com uma perna às costas. Eu consulto este [Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/) para este tipo de coisas. Mas é trabalhoso.

Comment: Conhece outros autores contemporâneos do Eça de Queiroz, em Portugal, que também escreviam `trem`? Alguma chance há de ele ter captado o `trem` dos seus contactos do Brasil, não?

Comment: Ainda existem o trem de cozinha e o de aterragem em Portugal!

Comment: Ramalho Ortigão, em *Cartas a Emília* :"Parecia não poder com as pernas e não me falava senão na hora de partir e no perigo de perder o ***comboio,*** isto 3 horas antes da hora da partida do ***trem***." Mas é certamente possível que a linguagem dos escritores não fosse representativa. Eles liam-se uns aos outros.

Comment: Parece que nesses exemplos citados, tanto na pergunta quanto no comentário, **trem** e **comboio** são revezados por estilismo. Mesmo assim, ficamos sem saber a origem do **trem**. Pode ser até que a palavra tenha sido levada pelos imigrantes portugueses no Brasil, e que tenha surgido primeiramente em Portugal.

Comment: Também me parece ser esse o caso nessas frases. Mas eu escolhia-as exatamente por terem ***trem*** e ***comboio*** na mesma frase ou quase. O Coelho Neto, que eu tenho andado a ler, parece usar as duas palavras aleatoriamente. *A Cidade e as Serras* já li há mais tempo, e não me lembro. O texto completo está disponível online no link que eu indico, se quiseres fazer um estudo da coisa...

Comment: @felipe.zkn, escapou-me na altura a tua pergunta: sim, diz-se *trem de cozinha* e *trem de aterragem* em Portugal.

Comment: @jean Nem o Ngram nos ajudaria nesta matéria. Andei a ver [neste Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/), e *trem* era muito usado na altura em Portugal com outros significados, especialmente uma carruagem de passageiros puxada por cavalos. E no Brasil usava-se muito *comboio* também com outros signficados. Aparece muito, por exemplo, na obra de Euclides da Cunha. Creio que era usado para designar uma caravana com equipamento militar.

Comment: No Algarve parece usar-se mais a palavra *trem* que *combóio*... Há por ai um "Algarve" para comfirmar...

Answer (score 3):

Repare que o dicionário de Português Europeu da [Porto Editora](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/trem) tem uma entrada em *trem* para:

> carro de cavalos destinado ao transporte de pessoas; carruagem

e é nesse sentido que apareçe em Eça de Queiroz, ou ainda uma daquelas carruagens puxadas por animais de tração sobre carris, mais tarde puxadas por motores elétricos, definidos como Bonde no Brasil ou Elétrico em Portugal. No caso da ferrovia refere-se explicitamente à carruagem motora ou seja à locomotiva.

Em Portugal trem nunca significou comboio, no sentido que hoje temos, de várias carruagens alinhadas e puxadas por uma motora sobre carris.

Assim, no Brasil adotou-se por generalização a grafia *trem*, como em Inglês, Francês ou Espanhol, mesmo para um conjunto de trens, ou um trem e várias carruagens. Em Portugal, continuou a usar-se a expressão *comboio*, que sempre se usou, pois faz referência à expressão que sempre teve na língua, mesmo antes do aparecimento da ferrovia, ou seja:

> conjunto de viaturas de transporte de mercadorias ou de pessoas que
>   seguem, geralmente em fila, para o mesmo destino

E é neste sentido que Coelho Netto grafa a palavra *comboio*, pois tratava-se, não de um, mas de várias carruagens seguidas em fila por certo ao longo de um carril e eventualmente puxadas por um trem.

Resumindo, com a evolução da ferrovia e das máquinas a vapor começou a ser tecnicamente possível puxar várias carruagens em simultâneo, o que não era possível com animais de tração. Era necessário pois denominar esse conjunto alinhado de carruagens. No Brasil, como em Inglês, Francês ou Espanhol, generalizou-se a unidade trem, ou seja, carruagem, para todo o conjunto. Em Portugal, adotou-se uma palavra diferente, que já existia, e que fazia exatamente referência a esse tipo de conjuntos.

Comment: Eu li *A Cidade e as Serras*. Podes verificar [aqui no livro](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bv000081.pdf) que *trem* significa nesta passagem *comboio* e não carruagem puxada por animais. Ctr F "condutor" encontra-te a passagem em causa. Expandi também a citação na pergunta. Quanto ao Coelho Netto, é claro que ele está a falar da possibilidade de colisão de dois comboios/trens. Repara: «e no **trem**? Se a gente vê vir, **na mesma linha, outro comboio**».

Comment: @Jacinto releia o que escrevi. No texto em apreço refere-se que _um condutor, (...) trepou ao salão e por ele soubemos (..) que o trem (...)_. Eça, apesar de citar várias vezes a palavra comboio anteriormente para se referir ao local onde estão, refere-se apenas à palavra trem quando surge o condutor, referindo-se obviamente à carruagem motora, ou seja, à locomotiva, aquela que antes da máquina a vapor, tal como um trem no sentido de carroça, era puxada por cavalos ou animais de tração. _Trem_ vem do Latim _traginare_, uma forma do verbo _trahere_, “puxar, arrastar”.

Comment: *Condutor* significa ali «empregado que cobra e/ou recolhe passagens em bondes e trens»; é um anglicismo [vê Aulete, aceção 9)](http://www.aulete.com.br/condutor). Eu li o livro *todo*. O protagonista viaja de Paris para Portugal de comboio. O episódio em causa acontece em Espanha durante a viajem. Em momento algum a viajem foi interrompida por trajeto em carruagem de tração animal. *Trem* aparece de novo logo a seguir: «Se o trem de Salamanca tivesse abalado?» (evidentemente o 'comboio de Salamanca' referido anteriormente) e mais duas vezes umas linhas mais abaixo (comentário seguinte)

Comment: « O **trem** arquejava, rompendo o vasto da planura desolada. E a cada apito era um alvoroço. Medina?... Não! algum sumido apeadeiro, onde o **trem** se atardava, esfalfado, resfolgando, enquanto dormentes figuras encarapuçadas, embrulhadas em mantas, rondavam sob o telheiro do barracão, que as lanternas baças tornavam mais soturno. Jacinto esmurrava o joelho: - “Mas pôr que pára este infame **comboio**? Não há tráfico, não há gente! Ó esta Espanha!...” A sineta badalava, moribunda. De novo fendíamos a noite e a borrasca.»

Comment: @Jacinto, claramente não leu o que escrevi. O trem refere-se à **locomotiva**, ou seja, à carruagem motora, pois é essa que tem a **tração** (*trem* vem do Latim *traginare*, uma forma do verbo *trahere*, “puxar", "arrastar", tendo a mesma origem que tração). Um trem mais as carruagens reboque formam um **comboio**. Já trabalhei no meio ferroviário.

Comment: De facto escapou-me a parte em que dizes que *trem* significa aqui *locomotiva*. Nunca vi isso em lado nenhum. Tens referências para sustentar essa tese?

Answer (score 0):

Comboio é comumente usado no Brasil para referir-se a um grupo. Por exemplo, caminhoneiros viajando cada um com seu caminhão, mas como um grupo (pela companhia em viagem ou segurança).

Comment: Eduardo, *comboio* vem do francês *convoi*, que vem do latim [conviare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comboio), _ir pela **via** **com**_. Creio que se aplicou primeiro a navios entre Índia, Brasil e Portugal. Ainda aparece com o significado de *trem* no [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=comboio). Agora ao que parece já foi usado no Brasil (vê o extrato do Colheo Neto). E a pergunta é quando é que se deixou de usar.

Comment: OK, retirei o comentário inapropriado.

Answer (score 0):

Ao que me foi ensinado quando criança, já há décadas, comboio pode ser sinônimo de trem de ferro (reduzido para trem)... Trem propriamente é palavra que pode designar qualquer coisa, como ainda hoje se usa em Minas Gerais

Answer (score -3):

Trem **não significa** comboio. Nem nessa frase.

Trem é uma palavra que denomina conjunto.

> Trem de cozinha -> Conjunto de Utensílios de Cozinha
>
> Trem de aterragem -> Conjunto de Rodas para aterrar um avião
>
> Trem (Numa Locomotiva) -> Conjunto de Carruagens *

- Enquanto que um conjunto de Carruagens pode ser denominado por comboio, um comboio tem não só um conjunto de carruagens, mas também (originalmente) uma carruagem dedicada à locomoção das carruagens, pelo que

> **que o trem, muito atrasado**

Refere-se não ao comboio, mas ás carruagens do comboio que são utilizadas como transporte. Isto em sentido literal, visto que neste caso ao se referir às carruagens restantes, o sujeito refere o comboio.

Comment: Por que o termo *carruagem* não inclui as carruagens de locomoção? Ou, se inclui, então um comboio é um trem de carruagens, então por que não se pode usar o termo *trem* para referir a um comboio inteiro?

Comment: Significa. Só não significa neste caso. trem significa conjunto de carruagens. Neste caso o narrador refere-se às carruagens que são atreladas, devido ao que contêm. Eça de Queiroz, e Gil Vicente são dois autores portugueses que usam este tipo de falsos sinónimos em obras clássicas. Apesar de ser algo bastante comum na linguagem corrente. O exemplo do texto é um mau exemplo porque não é literal, mas sim uma representação. O trem, não se refere verdadeiramente às carruagens, mas às maneiras que Jacinto (o Sujeito a quem o autor se refere) deixa para trás quando deixa França.

Comment: OK, quer dizer então que você não está a responder à pergunta original (que é sobre a origem da diferença entre o uso de *comboio* e *trem* em Brasil e Portugal), mas está a falar das palavras dos autores portugueses? Neste caso poderia editar a resposta para esclarecer isto? Porque quando olhei "trem não significa comboio", no contexto duma "Resposta à Pergunta", imaginei que estivesse a dizer que *trem* no Brasil não significa *comboio*.

Comment: Eu expliquei isso. Trem significa conjunto. Tanto de carruagens (que pode não ser de TODAS as carruagens de uma locomotiva), como de utensílios de cozinha. Comboio = Conjunto de todas as carruagens de uma locomotiva. Trem = conjunto de carruagens de uma locomotiva

Comment: @DanGetz e Oak: Questão menor: parece-me muito estranho que *trem* na citação do Eça ou do Ortigão (comentários) designe só as carruagens com exclusão da locomotiva; o mesmo nesta passagem de *O Conde de Abranhos* também do Eça, «prodigalizou histórias de
velocidades maiores [...] contou outros feitos, só comparáveis à velocidade de um trem expresso». Quais são as provas para fundamentar essa afirmação? Isto é uma questão lateral que não responde à minha pergunta: quando é que *trem* deixou em Portugal de  designar um conjunto de carruagens (independentemente de incluir ou não a locomotiva).